# Union of two characteristic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have proved intersection of two characteristic subgroup is characteristic but when I want to prove this for union I got stuck.  Is union of two characteristic subgroup is characteristic subgroup?  If yes then how can I prove?  If not give me a counter example

Comment: As has been pointed out, the set-theoretic union of two subgroups is not usually a subgroup, but the join $\langle H,K \rangle$ is a subgroup (by definition), and it is characteristic if both $H$ and $K$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any subgroup of a cyclic group is characteristic. So in $\Bbb Z_6$, the subgroups $\{0,3\}$ and $\{0,2,4\}$ are characteristic but their union is even not a subgroup!

Comment: Excellent,,  thank u

Comment: You are welcome! The proof of the result mentioned in the first line is easy. For the proof first consider it for two cases, namely, infinite and finite group. The first case is easy since there only two automorphisms in this case. Similarly handle the second case. If you already know the proof, just ignore this !

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ subgroups of $G$. Then $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H \subseteq K$ or $K \subseteq H$.

Thus, assuming that the union is a subgroup, you will be proving trivialities.